# An approach to store DataTable each time after changes into stack and be able to undo changes

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a DataTable (`my_dt`) that is a itemsSource of a DataGrid and user has the ability of making several changes into it like swapping rows and changing the time column of each row which the value in this column related to other rows meaning changing value in one row's time column would changes the time column of all the other rows beneath that row.

As the user want to roll back or undo changes that were unintended or for any other reason, I decided to create a stack of DataTable type and after each change I push the DataTable (`my_dt`) into stack and after clicking *Undo* button pop it and use clear and merge methods to bring back the DataTable and DataGrid to the state before last change by each click.

Is it a good idea to work on it or not?

By the way I don't want use `AccepChanges` and `RejectChanges` for that DataTable because in this case user can only undo one step of changes that he made.

The DataTable does not have more than 150 rows.

Example :

```
Stack<DataTable> st = new Stack<DataTable>();

private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    st.Push(ds.Tables["my_dt"].Copy());

    //Edit codes
}    

private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ds.Tables["my_dt"].Clear();
    ds.Tables["my_dt"].Merge(st.Pop());
}
```